# Как найти в тексте самое часто встречающеся слово?

Tags: python, словарь

```
text = "These people had a little window at the back of their house from which a splendid garden could be seen, which was full of the most beautiful flowers and herbs. It was, however, surrounded by a high wall, and no one dared to go into it because it belonged to an enchantress, who had great power and was dreaded by all the world."
t = text.replace(',', '')
#print(t)
print(max(t.split(), key=len))
print(min(t.split(), key=len))

my_di = dict()
for line in text:
    line = line.rstrip()
    #print(line)
    wrds = line.split()
    #print(wrds)
    for w in wrds:
        my_di[w] = my_di.get(w,0) + 1
#print(my_di)
largest = -1
word = None
for k,v in my_di.items():
    if v > largest:
        largest = v
        word = k
print(word,largest)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот так вот для слов, разделённых пробелами (можно сначала удалить знаки пунктуации, как вы сделали):

```
import collections

text = "These people had a little window at the back of their house from which a splendid garden could be seen, which was full of the most beautiful flowers and herbs. It was, however, surrounded by a high wall, and no one dared to go into it because it belonged to an enchantress, who had great power and was dreaded by all the world."

print(collections.Counter(text.split()).most_common(1))
```