# Как из текста получить словарь частоты нахождения слов?

Tags: python, словари

```py
import collections

text = "These people had a little window at the back of their house from which " \
       "splendid garden could be seen, which was full of the most beautiful " \
       "flowers and herbs. It was, however, surrounded by a high wall, and no " \
       "one dared to go into it because it belonged to an enchantress, who had " \
       "great power and was dreaded by all the world."
```

Comment: Нужно получить сайт. s = ['yes', '1', '2']

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как найти в тексте самое часто встречающеся слово?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1171291/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be)

Comment: Пожалуйста, вставьте код в специальный блок (в редакторе вопроса есть кнопка "добавить код"). И опишите более подробно, что вы хотите получить

Answer (score 5):

```
from string import punctuation
from collections import Counter

res = dict(Counter(text
                   .translate(str.maketrans('', '', punctuation))
                   .split())
           .most_common())
```

---

```
In [71]: res
Out[71]:
{'a': 3,
 'the': 3,
 'was': 3,
 'and': 3,
 'had': 2,
 'of': 2,
 'which': 2,
 'by': 2,
 'to': 2,
 'it': 2,
 'These': 1,
 'people': 1,
 'little': 1,
 'window': 1,
 'at': 1,
 'back': 1,
 'their': 1,
 'house': 1,
 'from': 1,
 'splendid': 1,
 'garden': 1,
 'could': 1,
 'be': 1,
 'seen': 1,
 'full': 1,
 'most': 1,
 'beautiful': 1,
 'flowers': 1,
 'herbs': 1,
 'It': 1,
 'however': 1,
 'surrounded': 1,
 'high': 1,
 'wall': 1,
 'no': 1,
 'one': 1,
 'dared': 1,
 'go': 1,
 'into': 1,
 'because': 1,
 'belonged': 1,
 'an': 1,
 'enchantress': 1,
 'who': 1,
 'great': 1,
 'power': 1,
 'dreaded': 1,
 'all': 1,
 'world': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text = "These people had a little window at the back of their house from which a splendid garden could be seen, which was full of the most beautiful flowers and herbs. It was, however, surrounded by a high wall, and no one dared to go into it because it belonged to an enchantress, who had great power and was dreaded by all the world."

l = text.split(' ')
print(*sorted(l, key=l.count))
```

Comment: а где же сам частотный словарь? ;)